# Iterate over multiple dataframe rows at the same time

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 16 different dataframes with the same number of rows/columns and another 2 separate dataframes with that same shape that i'm using to compare with the 16 dataframe values.

I need to loop over all dataframes at the same time, and compare all row values with the separate dataframes, and then create another dataframe with the results like so:

comparison: `sum(row_values_of_dataframe) - sum(row_values_of_reference)`. In the example below, the cell `df_a_ref_a` is equal to (1 + 2 + 3 + 4) - (5 + 5 + 5 + 5) = -10

```py
Dataframe A (df_a)

col1 | col 2 | col 3 | col 4
1       2       3       4
2       4       6       8
[...]

Dataframe B (df_b)

col1 | col 2 | col 3 | col 4
10      5       2       1
4       4       6       2
[...]

Reference Dataframe 1 (ref_1)
col1 | col 2 | col 3 | col 4
5       5       5       5
5       5       5       5
[...]

Reference Dataframe 2 (ref_2)
col1 | col 2 | col 3 | col 4
3       3       3       3
3       3       3       3
[...]
```

Final dataframe should be:

```py
df_a_ref_1 | df_a_ref_2 | df_b_ref_1 | df_b_ref_2 | ....
    -10          -2           -2           6        ....
     0           8            -4           4
[...]
```

This behaviour resembles `zip()` function in python.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Are you familiar with vectorization? It's way faster than iteration, and it looks very suitable for this kind of problem

Answer (score 1):

Yo can store your dataframes in two different list, and then iterate through them simultaneously appending a new column for each dataframe.

Here is an example with 2 datafames (you only need to add the other 14).

```
list_dataframes = [df, df2]
list_dataframes_references = [df_reference, df_reference2]
list_names = ["a", "b"]

final_df = pd.DataFrame()

for i in range(len(list_dataframes)):
    a_sum = list_dataframes[i].sum(axis=1)
    a_ref_sum = list_dataframes_references[i].sum(axis=1)

    final_df.loc[:, "columna_{}".format(list_names[i])] = a_sum - a_ref_sum
```

Here you are avoiding iterating inside the dataframes using vectorization (as the user @bug_spray said), which is more efficient and clean.

Answer (score 0):

I didnt' understand the exact names you gave to your dataframes, but here is how you can achive that:

```
new_df = pd.DataFrame()
for df, ref in #loop over dfs and refs:
    new_df[#column name] = df.to_numpy().sum(1) - ref.to_numpy().sum(1)
```

If you have like a list of the dfs and refs you can do `for df, ref in zip(dfs, refs)`

Comment: Also, if you want to compare all dfs with all refs, you just have to do 2 for loops.

Comment: I must run all dfs simultaneously (one row at a time), because i will create a new dataframe and assign each calculation (row-df minus row-ref) to a new cell.

Comment: Didn't get the simultaneously part, do you want to parallelize your computation?

Answer (score 0):

Use vectorization.

```py
A = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3,4],[2,4,6,8]])
B = pd.DataFrame([[10,5,2,1],[4,4,6,2]])
# ...

dfs = [A, B, ...]

ref_a1 = (A - 5).sum(1)
ref_a2 = (A - 3).sum(1)
ref_b1 = (B - 5).sum(1)
ref_b2 = (B - 3).sum(1)
```

Put that in a loop if you want...

```py
dfs = [A,B,...]
result_names = ['df_a_ref_1', 'df_a_ref_2', 'df_b_ref_1', ...]

res = []
for df in dfs:
    res += [(df-5).sum(1)]
    res += [(df-3).sum(1)]

results = pd.DataFrame(res, columns=result_names)
```